# Multithreading example for x number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Multithreading world, I am not sure how should I write a java application that can invoke x number of threads, if we pass x number of threads from the command prompt. Just Like if we are passing

```
java –jar pds_client_batch.jar <number of threads>
```

and here if number of threads is passed as 20 then it should run for twenty threads. Any simple example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Example
{
  private class DumbThread implements Runnable
  {
    public void run()
    { 
      System.out.println("Thread ran");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for (int x = 0; x < input; x++)
      new Thread(new DumbThread()).start();
  }
}
```

Now, if you want it to do something useful...

Edit: made more complete.  It still does nothing useful.  Also it doesn't do even basic error checking.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me simple working example, then I will be able to understand more, as these things are slightly new to me.

Comment: You should also join the threads before leaving main, otherwise you won't see any output.

Comment: You will if you're running from a command prompt or IDE, but not if you're executing where running it pops up the output window.  This is, of course, a very naive implementation and anything useful would probably want to join because it would want to actually use the work done.

Answer (score 1):

You could also you an executorService like [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). and pass in the number of threads you want it to use.

Comment: ,Can you give me simple working example, then I will be able to understand more, as these things are slightly new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you are encouraged to use thread pools for better management of threads. You can create a fixed thread pool:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private int id;

    public ThreadTask(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I am task " + id);
    }
}

public class TestPool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // create thread pool with given size
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size); 

        // queue some tasks
        for(int i = 0; i < 3 * size; i++) {
            service.submit(new ThreadTask(i));
        }


        // wait for termination        
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, Can you explain little bit, what's happening here, So suppose if size is 10 then it means number of threads is 10, then what does in the for loop do? means 3 * 10 = 30 so it will be running 30 times? And any meaningful task I can in in the run method right?

Comment: @Nevzz03: Yes, you are creating 30 tasks that are executed by 10 threads. You can put your task code in the `run` method.

Comment: So If I am putting my task code in the run method so it will mean that I am running that task code with the use ten threads simultaneously? So it will be running that task simultaneously.

Comment: @Nevzz03: No, it will mean that the task is run by one of the 10 threads. The task itself cannot be split between multiple threads. That's why I'm creating 30 tasks, because each one will be executed by a different thread.

Comment: @Tudor, So Suppose if I add something in the run method, then each task is run by each thread independently right? There will be no intereference between the threads right? Like if first thread change the value and at that time second thread enters the loop.

Comment: @Tudor, And suppose if I need that if thread one is finish then only thread two should run and then thread three should run. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RaihanJamal: So you want the tasks to run in a sequence?

Comment: @tudor, yes tudor. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Raihan Jamal: You can use an `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and submit the tasks there. Then they will all execute on the same thread one after the other.

Comment: @tudor that's what I am looking for, how can I add this line in the code?

Comment: Just replace `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size)` with `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`. Now all your tasks will be executed in order by a single thread.